# Deploying apps created using QuickBooks SDK

Tags: vb6, deployment, quickbooks

I have written an application that interfaces with QB Pro in VB6. I would now like to deploy it to the client's system. What are the DLLs and/or MSMs that I should include in the installer?

I am using the Visual Studio Installer to create the MSI.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to install copies of the Intuit SDK DLLs. The merge modules you need are in the SDK, in path Program Files\Intuit\QBSDK\tools. In this directory you will find both stand-alone installation executables and merge modules. In the MergeModules directory, you will find merge modules for both QBFC and QBXMLRP2.

If you are using Visual Studio to create an MSI the best way to add the correct merge modules is to add the Intuit SDK MergeModules directory to the search path of your setup project.  To do this, select the project in project explorer, then click the property pane or hit F4. This should bring you to the setup project properties where you should be able to see the SearchPath property.

Once you have added the MergeModules directory to SearchPath, you should see the merge modules added automatically in the Detected Dependencies folder of your setup project. You will see both the Intuit module (either QBFC or QBXMLRP2) and also the xerces parser merge module (the Xerces parser is used by the SDK).

Comment: I realize this is an old post, is there an update to this for the SDK13?
VS installer doesn't add the merge modules in like you said with the search path, unfortunately. Not sure why. The workaround is to install the SDK on everyone's machine before installing the app. Been fighting this conundrum for a year or so now. Adding Merge Modules manually does not work, either (Intuit says your method should work).

Comment: I haven't touched the QBSDK for over 3 years at this point, so take this with a grain of salt. I think your problem is with VS support for MSI packages, not with the Intuit SDK. Microsoft moved from MSI to one-click installation as the preferred install platform years ago. You shouldn't need to install the entire SDK on client machines, Intuit provides a smaller runtime install as I recall. Good luck!

Comment: I found it. Unfortunately, with the inherent limitations in 1 click (incompatible with so much legacy code), the ideal way is w/ MM (which, as per Intuit support, has a licensing issue making their merge modules moot - why they created them is a mystery), but the workaround is to run a second installer routine to launch "QBFC13_0Installer.exe" during setup (or do this manually, but most people will just complain about an extra step).